# How to get all elements from a list without the last element?

Tags: groovy

The following Groovy code

```
    lines = ['0','1','2','3','4','5']
    println lines[1..lines.size()-1]
    println lines[1..-1]
    println lines[1..<lines.size()-1]
    println lines[1..<-1]
    println lines[1..<-2]
    println lines[1..-2]
```

produces this output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 0]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Since `-1` is the index of the last element in the list, the first two make sense (ranges in Groovy include the end element instead of omitting it as everywhere else in Java :-( )

Line #3 is the desired output (list without first and last element).

I'm worried about the output #4: Why do I get `[1, 0]` for `1..-1`?

Also `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` for the range `1..<-2` seems wrong.

Why does that happen?

Comment: Shouldn't the ranges start from 0 instead of 1 if you want to include all elements but the last? (in your examples, you're always excluding the first element)

Comment: In my case, I also don't want the first element but that's not the main point of my question.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The best way to take all elements but the last one, in my opinion, is to use the [`take`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/List.html#take(int)) method:

```
def list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
assert list.take(list.size() - 1) == ['a', 'b']
```

It behaves properly in the corner case where size == 1:

```
def list = ['one']
assert list.take(list.size() - 1) == []
```

Though I'd prefer it to throw an exception in the case size == 0, but the behavior is not that bad:

```
def list = []
assert list.take(list.size() - 1) == []
```

You can also use `list[0..<list.size()-1]` (your third example) and it will behave the same except for the empty list, in which case it will throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, but i think is not as readable as the `take` counterpart.

---

Another acceptable solution is using `list[0..-2]` (your last example), which i think looks much more elegant, but unfortunately breaks when size == 1 with an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

---

In your examples (i'll assume that you meant to use 0 as the starting index instead of 1 if you wanted to include all elements but the last one):

`lines[0..lines.size()-1]` is equivalent to `lines[0..-1]` because the `getAt(Range)` method of lists will treat ranges with negative indexes the same way as`getAt(Integer)` does, i.e. as accessing the `(list.size() + negativeIndex)`'th element of the list. Therefore `list[0..-1]` is the same as saying "from first element to last" and it's the same as copying the list; and `list[-1..0]` is the same as "from last to first" and it's equivalent to `list.reverse()` :)

The problem with the other non-inclusive range example is that the non-inclusive ranges are being evaluated before the list access and they evaluate to an incorrect inclusive range. For example, `0..<-2` evaluates to `0..-1`, and that's why it's returning all the elements. `0..<-1` evaluates to `0..0` and it returns only the first element.

Notice that the empty range is a special case. It's denoted as `0..<0` and it doesn't have an inclusive equivalent (so Groovy won't do any magic conversion here). And that's why `list[0..<list.size()-1]` works when size == 1 (the range evaluates to the empty range) while `list[0..-2]` doesn't :)

Comment: +1 FWIW, the _'magic conversion'_ [happens here](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethodsSupport.java#L36), and the returned `RangeInfo` object [is used](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.java#L4634) to call the [standard Java `List.subList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList%28int,%20int%29) method

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this has changed since epideman wrote his answer, but you can get the whole list without the last element with `0..<-1`:

```
assert ["foo"][0..<-1] == []
assert ["foo", "bar"][0..<-1] == ["foo"]
assert ["foo", "bar", "baz"][0..<-1] == ["foo", "bar"]


// blows up if empty, here take is better
assert [][0..<-1] == []  // BOOM

// if you want null safe, use take
assert [].take(-1) == []
```

This is with groovy 2.2.1.

Answer (score 3):

Since Groovy 2.4 you can use the [init()](http://mrhaki.blogspot.se/2015/01/groovy-goodness-getting-all-but-last.html) method:

```
lines = ['0','1','2','3','4','5']
assert lines.init() == ['0','1','2','3','4']
```