# How to get the all but the last item of this given list in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

It might sound simple, but am kind of struglling with the logic of how to print all but ignor the last element in the list. Any suggestion would be helpful.

### code

```
    def list = [
        'homePage',
        'productPage',
        'basketPage',
        'categoryPage'
    ]
    def counter = 1
    list.each { element ->
        if (element == list.last()){
            list.remove(3)
            println "Item $counter -" + element 
        }
    }
```

### Expected output

Item 1 - homePage
Item 2 - productPage
Item 3 - basketPage

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get all elements from a list without the last element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10516191/how-to-get-all-elements-from-a-list-without-the-last-element)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Groovy supports range operations on collections:

```
print list[0..list.size-2]
```

This will print:

```
[homePage, productPage, basketPage]
```

Answer (score 4):

It can be shorter than @SteveD answer:

```
println list[0..-2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
list.take(list.size() - 1)
```

​
With println:

```
list.take(list.size() - 1).eachWithIndex { element, i ->
    println "Item " + i + " - " + element
}
```

​